# Работа со структурами

Tags: c, указатели, список

Помогите,пожалуйста, найти ошибку. Нужно удалить из списка все звенья,содержащие указатели на строки равные строке `str`.
Вот код моей функции:

```
struct Node *delete_all(struct Node *list, const char *str){
    struct Node *temp,*a;
    if((strcmp(list->word,str))!=0){
    a=list;
    while(a->next->next!=NULL){
        if((strcmp(a->next->word,str)==0)){
            a->next=a->next->next;
            free(a->next->word);
            free(a->next);
        }
        else
            a=a->next;
    }
    }
    else{
        struct Node *temmp;
        temmp=list->next;
        free(list->word);
        free(list);
        return temmp;
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: А ошибка-то в чем?

Comment: @mango44  Покажите определение struct Node.

Comment: struct Node {
    char *word;
    struct Node *next;
};

Comment: Ошибка в том,что он всегда выводит только два последних слова.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем случае указатель `list` может быть равен `NULL`. Поэтому уже начальный код функции неверный и может являться причиной неопределенного поведения программы

```
struct Node *delete_all(struct Node *list, const char *str){
    struct Node *temp,*a;
    if((strcmp(list->word,str))!=0){
    //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ list можкт быть равен NULL
    a=list;
    while(a->next->next!=NULL){
    //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ поле a->next может быть равно NULL
    //....
```

К тому же если первый же узел имеет строку, совпадающую с заданной строкой, то вы удаляете только этот узел. Другие узлы, имеющую совпадающую строку, не удаляются, так как происходит выход из функции.

И условие в данном цикле

```
    while(a->next->next!=NULL){
```

не имеет смысла, так как если список имеет только два узла, и второй узел будет иметь совпадающую строку, то из-за условия в цикле, этот второй узел не будет обработан, так как `a->next->next` будет рано `NULL`.

Функция может быть написана следующим образом

```
struct Node * delete_all( struct Node *list, const char *str )
{
    struct Node *curr = list;
    struct Node *prev = NULL;

    while ( curr )
    {
        if ( strcmp( curr->word, str ) == 0 )
        {
            struct Node *tmp = curr;
            if ( prev )
            {
                prev->next = curr->next;
            }
            else
            {
                list = curr->next;
            }
            curr = curr->next;
            free( tmp->word );
            free( tmp );
        }
        else
        {
            prev = curr;
            curr = curr->next;
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```

Comment: @mango44 Не за что. Спрашивайте еще.:)